# Retrieving list elements in Python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, element

I'm a beginner attempting to learn Python. I am familiarising myself with the list data type; I've defined the following list:

```
>>> numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Typing:

```
>>> numbers[0]
1
>>> numbers[1]
2
>>> numbers[2]
3
>>> numbers[3]
4
```

Given this, why do I get the following when I attempt to retrieve the following list elements:

```
>>> numbers[0:3]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Why isn't the list element '4' included in the response from the interpreter?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slice notation does not include the last element (similar to the `range()` function in that respect). If you want to include the last element, simply omit an index. Also, the default start is the beginning, so you don't need `0` there either:

```
>>> numbers[:]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Note that this is a (shallow) copy of `numbers`. If you save a reference to it, you can mutate it without affecting the original `numbers`.

Answer (score 1):

That's how slicing works in Python. To quote a [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html):

> Note how the start is always included, and the end always excluded.
>   This makes sure that `s[:i]` + `s[i:]` is always equal to `s`.

The example uses a string, but slicing works the same way with lists.

Answer (score 0):

numbers[0:3] list from 0 up to 3 but 3 is excluded (like range(0,3))